# trying to decode RS485 protocol

Tags: protocols, rs485

I am trying to decode signal that two devices are using over RS485.

I captured signal, from which i got baud rate (57600, one bit is 17,3us long):

[Screenshot of the signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmi9b.png)

This signal is BIN: 0000000000010010001001111110011110011011111110...

Then i wrote simple capture program in arduino:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  Serial1.begin(57600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial1.available()){
    byte temp=Serial1.read();
    if(temp==0){
      Serial.println();
    }else{
      Serial.print(temp,HEX);
    }
  }
}
```

Which got me following output:

https://justpaste.it/6sw5g

What is my next step in decoding this communication?

Comment: Please share the specification of the protocol you want to decode. Otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: What kind of devices?

Comment: @AdrianW: the thing is, that i don't know the protocol. The devices (furnace and regulator) communicate between each other via rs485 line.

Comment: If you don't know the protocol, it just can by anything. You are in the position of the future recipients of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_message having almost no clue of the structure and content of the message. You really _need_ to ask the manufacturer for the protocol specification. Otherwise you don't have any chance to decode it.

Comment: Well, i was hoping, that devices are using some known protocol (e.g. MODBUS), and someone with knowledge of that protocols would see this from my captures.